# How to implement bootstrap corousel with angular ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, carousel

When I am trying to use ng-repeat inside corousel-inner the corousel is not working properly, how to use carousel with ng-repeat ?

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exact but seems like what you want.

```
<div class="container" ng-show="ifImages">
<br>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-repeat="image in images">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="$index" ng-class="{'active': $index == 0}"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" ng-repeat="image in images">
        <div class="item" ng-class="{'active': $index == 0}">
            <img bn-lazy-src="{{image.fullPath}}" title="{{image.description}}" alt="missing" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>{{image.name}}</h3>
                <p>{{image.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```