# How to use bootstrap carousel with Angular correctly

Tags: angular, user-interface, bootstrap-4

There are many questions on stackoveflow. I've gone through some of them:

1. [How to implement bootstrap corousel with angular ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086381/how-to-implement-bootstrap-corousel-with-angular-ng-repeat)
2. [How to use carousel with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553020/how-to-use-carousel-with-angular) : 9 months, no answer.
3. [Slides in Bootstrap Carousel are not ... only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307403/slides-in-bootstrap-carousel-are-not-coming-in-horizontal-form-slides-are-comin/52310896#52310896) : 1+ year, no proper answer

Then I tried following this article:

1. [How to use bootstrap 4 carousel in angular 5 | 6](https://yogeshdotnet.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-carousel-in-angular-5-6/)
   and many more.

My code is not working properly. My images are stacked one over the other without animation. No error or warning on console.

Here is my code:
**carousel.component.html**

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='col-12'>
    <ngb-carousel>
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <img src="https://content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%" alt="Random first slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>10 seconds between slides...</h3>
          <p>This carousel uses customized default values.</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
         OTHER 4-5 slides
      </ng-template> 
    </ngb-carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

**carousel.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ NgbCarouselConfig ]
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
    config.interval = 2000;
    config.wrap = true;
    config.keyboard = false;
    config.pauseOnHover = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';
...
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgbModule ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Looking into my code this way can very painful. So here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anrd4b).
And here is the screenshot (Zoomed out to 30% to accommodate everything in one image):
[image]

Please help me.

Right now I'm calling images from the internet but later I'll keep images locally in my **assets/images** folder.

And `bootstrap` is not hard and fast. Please feel free to suggest some other options also.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have not initialized the carousel module in your app.module file so the app doesnt know what a carousel is.

you will need to add  the following module to your global declarations

```
import { NgbdCarouselBasic } from './carousel-basic';
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgbModule],
  declarations: [NgbdCarouselBasic],
  exports: [NgbdCarouselBasic],
  bootstrap: [NgbdCarouselBasic]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten styles:)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

But the better way store this style locally and add them to angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import BrowserAnimationsModule in your app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ],
```

source :
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-bootstrap-carousel-exampleexample.html